# Single module User for both Ecto and Open API Specs?

Tags: swagger, elixir, swagger-ui, openapi, phoenix-framework

at https://hexdocs.pm/open_api_spex/3.2.0/readme.html there's a definition of a module User

```
defmodule MyApp.Schemas do
  alias OpenApiSpex.Schema

  defmodule User do
    @behaviour OpenApiSpex.Schema
    @derive [Jason.Encoder]
    @schema %Schema{
      title: "User",
      description: "A user of the app",
      type: :object,
      properties: %{
        id: %Schema{type: :integer, description: "User ID"},
        name:  %Schema{type: :string, description: "User name"},
        email: %Schema{type: :string, description: "Email address", format: :email},
        inserted_at: %Schema{type: :string, description: "Creation timestamp", format: :datetime},
        updated_at: %Schema{type: :string, description: "Update timestamp", format: :datetime}
      },
      required: [:name, :email],
      example: %{
        "id" => 123,
        "name" => "Joe",
        "email" => "joe@gmail.com"
      }
      "x-struct": __MODULE__
    }
    def schema, do: @schema
    defstruct Map.keys(@schema.properties)
  end
```

In order to avoid re-describing it like that for Open API Specs whilst having already done so for Ecto, is it possible to combine the two definitions in a single module somehow? That is, my Ecto schema User would serve its purpose for Open API Specs too. With some required tweaks.

And if I do combine them, won't  this mess up with the methods of the 2 modules and other things?

Comment: Sometimes re-describing a schema is a feature not a bug even though it means more busy-work: having a layer of abstraction ensures backend implementation details are not fixed to the front-end. It is possible for a single module to implement multiple behaviours: it's not the same as OO inheritance, implementing a behaviour is just a guarantee that the module implements specific callbacks.